# NestedScroll overlayTop AppBar error

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

Problem is that just I can't user overlayTop but I've got Support Design Library 23.1 included and every component usable just this one not

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nes_scroll"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_overlayTop="44dp">
    ...
```

and here's error:

Error:(50) No resource identifier found for attribute `behavior_overlayTop` in package `com.scroll.example`

also it's not usable in Java source too, it's just red line and offers to create class related to `setOverlapTop()`.